# Python pickle: fix \r characters before loading

Tags: python, carriage-return, pickle

I got a pickled object (a list with a few numpy arrays in it) that was created on Windows and  apparently saved to a file loaded as text, not in binary mode (ie. with `open(filename, 'w')` instead of `open(filename, 'wb')`). Result is that now I can't unpickle it (not even on Windows) because it's infected with `\r` characters (and possibly more)? The main complaint is

```
ImportError: No module named multiarray
```

supposedly because it's looking for `numpy.core.multiarray\r`, which of course doesn't exist. Simply removing the `\r` characters didn't do the trick (tried both `sed -e 's/\r//g'` and, in python `s = file.read().replace('\r', '')`, but both break the file and yield a `cPickle.UnpicklingError` later on)

Problem is that I really need to get the data out of the objects. Any ideas how to fix the files?

**Edit:** On request, the first few hundred bytes of my file, Octal:

```
\x80\x02]q\x01(}q\x02(U\r\ntotal_timeq\x03G?\x90\x15r\xc9(s\x00U\rreaction_timeq\x04NU\x0ejump_directionq\x05cnumpy.core.multiarray\r\nscalar\r\nq\x06cnumpy\r\ndtype\r\nq\x07U\x02f8K\x00K\x01\x87Rq\x08(K\x03U\x01<NNNJ\xff\xff\xff\xffJ\xff\xff\xff\xffK\x00tbU\x08\x025\x9d\x13\xfc#\xc8?\x86Rq\tU\x14normalised_directionq\r\nh\x06h\x08U\x08\xf0\xf9,\x0eA\x18\xf8?\x86Rq\x0bU\rjump_distanceq\x0ch\x06h\x08U\x08\x13\x14\xea&\xb0\x9b\x1a@\x86Rq\rU\x04jumpq\x0ecnumpy.core.multiarray\r\n_reconstruct\r\nq\x0fcnumpy\r\nndarray\r\nq\x10K\x00\x85U\x01b\x87Rq\x11(K\x01K\x02\x85h\x08\x89U\x10\x87\x16\xdaEG\xf4\xf3?\x06`OC\xe7"\x1a@tbU\x0emovement_speedq\x12h\x06h\x08U\x08\\p\xf5[2\xc2\xef?\x86Rq\x13U\x0ctrial_lengthq\x14G@\t\x98\x87\xf8\x1a\xb4\xbaU\tconditionq\x15U\x0bhigh_mentalq\x16U\x07subjectq\x17K\x02U\x12movement_directionq\x18h\x06h\x08U\x08\xde\x06\xcf\x1c50\xfd?\x86Rq\x19U\x08positionq\x1ah\x0fh\x10K\x00\x85U\x01b\x87Rq\x1b(K\x01K\x02\x85h\x08\x89U\x10K\xb7\xb4\x07q=\x1e\xc0\xf2\xc2YI\xb7U&\xc0tbU\x04typeq\x1ch\x0eU\x08movementq\x1dh\x0fh\x10K\x00\x85U\x01b\x87Rq\x1e(K\x01K\x02\x85h\x08\x89U\x10\xad8\x9c9\x10\xb5\xee\xbf\xffa\xa2hWR\xcf?tbu}q\x1f(h\x03G@\t\xba\xbc\xb8\xad\xc8\x14h\x04G?\xd9\x99%]\xadV\x00h\x05h\x06h\x08U\x08\xe3X\xa9=\xc1\xb1\xeb?\x86Rq h\r\nh\x06h\x08U\x08\x88\xf7\xb9\xc1\t\xd6\xff?\x86Rq!h\x0ch\x06h\x08U\x08v\x7f\xeb\x11\xea5\r@\x86Rq"h\x0eh\x0fh\x10K\x00\x85U\x01b\x87Rq#(K\x01K\x02\x85h\x08\x89U\x10\xcd\xd9\x92\x9a\x94=\x06@]C\xaf\xef\xeb\xef\x02@tbh\x12h\x06h\x08U\x08-\x9c&\x185\xfd\xef?\x86Rq$h\x14G@\r\xb8W\xb2`V\xach\x15h\x16h\x17K\x02h\x18h\x06h\x08U\x08\x8e\x87\xd1\xc2
```

You may also download the [whole file](http://dl.dropbox.com/u/1418632/results.pickle) (22k).

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Presuming that the file was created with the default protocol=0 ASCII-compatible method, you should be able to load it anywhere by using `open('pickled_file', 'rU')` i.e. universal newlines.

If this doesn't work, show us the first few hundred bytes: `print repr(open('pickled_file', 'rb').read(200))` and paste the results into an edit of your question.

**Update** after file contents were published:

Your file starts with `'\x80\x02'`; it was dumped with protocol 2, the latest/best. Protocols 1 and 2 are **binary** protocols. Your file was written in **text** mode on Windows. This has resulted in each `'\n'` being converted to `'\r\n'` by the C runtime. Files should be opened in binary mode like this:

```
with open('result.pickle', 'wb') as f: # b for binary
    pickle.dump(obj, f, pickle.HIGHEST_PROTOCOL)

with open('result.pickle', 'rb') as f: # b for binary
    obj = pickle.load(f)
```

Docs are [here](http://docs.python.org/library/pickle.html#usage). This code will work portably on both Windows and non-Windows systems.

You can recover the original pickle image by reading the file in binary mode and then reversing the damage by replacing all occurrences of `'\r\n'` by `'\n'`. Note: This recovery procedure is necessary whether you are trying to read it on Windows or not.

Comment: +1 for info on the pickling protocol version. @Nkosinathi, you should mark this as the answer.

Comment: to add to the complication, if you GIT the file on windows, be default, GIT will turn '\n' to '\r\n', which would cause 'whatever module fails to load' error.

Comment: In my case (win10, python3.6,  atis.pkl from https://github.com/chsasank/ATIS.keras), replacing all occurrences of '\r\n' by '\n' in atis.pkl + pickle.load(fhandle, encoding='latin1') works out properly. If I were to omit encoding='latin1', the system would complain: UnicodeDecodeError: 'ascii' codec can't decode byte 0xe8 in position 0: ordinal not in range(128)

Answer (score 5):

Newlines in Windows aren't just `'\r'`, it's CRLF, or `'\r\n'`.

Give `file.read().replace('\r\n', '\n')` a try. You were previously deleting carriage returns that may not have actually been part of newlines.

Comment: +1: you got it!  This works on Mac OS X.  There are indeed isolated `\r` characters in the pickle file.

Comment: Brilliant, that solved it! Thanks a million, you saved 4 hours of very, very expensive work (and no, definitely not because of my salary... ;-)

Answer (score 0):

Can't you -- on Windows -- just open the file in text mode, the same way it was written, read it in and then write it out to another file opened properly in binary mode?

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried *unpickling* in text mode?  That is,

```
x = pickle.load(open(filename, 'r'))
```

(On Windows, of course.)

Comment: Nope, apparently Windows doesn't like it's own line endings...?