# ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'numpy.core.multiarray\r'

Tags: python-3.x, numpy

I am trying to load a pkl file,

```
pkl_file = open(sys.argv[1], 'rb')
world = pickle.load(pkl_file)
```

but I get an error from these lines

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "E:/python/test.py", line 186, in <module>
world = pickle.load(pkl_file)
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'numpy.core.multiarray\r'
```

I am using Windows 10, python 3.7, and installed four packages (numpy 1.17.2, opencv-python 4.1.1.26, pip 19.2.3, setuptools 41.2.0 ). I have tried to change "rb" to "r", but still got the error, how can I fix this?

Comment: Did you `import pickle`

Comment: yes, added a import pickle at the top

Comment: Did you import sys?  Please show all imports.

Comment: @fmw42 yes, obviously @bigbbb imported `sys`. The error is related to the fact that the pickled object is/contains a `numpy` object. Importing `numpy` may fix the issue, but I suspect this will still raise the same error because the newline character `/r` shouldn't be there.

Answer (score 2):

I think there are two problems here.

First, your pickle is or contains a [NumPy](https://numpy.org/) object, which is not part of the standard library. Therefore you must ensure that NumPy is installed into your current Python environment and imported **before** you try to load the pickled object. Depending on your setup, installation may be as simple as,

```
pip install numpy
```

Then you must add the line,

```py
import numpy as np
```

to the top of your script.

Second, it looks like Python is encountering [this issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8527241/python-pickle-fix-r-characters-before-loading), where your binary file was erroneously saved as text on Windows, resulting in resulted in each `'\n'` being converted to `'\r\n'`. To fix this, you must re-convert to `'\r\n'` back to `'\n'`. So long as the file isn't **huge**, this usually isn't very painful.

Here is a relatively complete example:

```py
import sys
import numpy as np

src = sys.argv[1]  # path to your file

data = open(src).read().replace('\r\n', '\n') # read and replace file contents
dst = src + ".tmp"
open(dst, "w").write(data) # save a temporary file

world = pickle.load(open(dst, "rb"), encoding='latin1')
```

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I just had to figure this out for myself, and I solved it. All you have to do is change all the "\r\n" to "\n". You can do this in multiple ways. You can go into Notepad++ and change line endings from CR LF to just LF. Or programmatically you can do

```
open(newfile, 'w', newline = '\n').write(open(oldfile, 'r').read())
```